# How to remove the GAESA cookie from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

This morning Google app engine added a cookie GAESA. I have embedded systems using micro controllers that use GAE as a rest api. The size of the cookie trigger the local max memory protection that I wrote. I can not change the embedded code as there are many systems off site. Is there a way to remove the GAESA cookie? I'm using Google app engine standard with python.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 4a77f57e1bf3be5f033c92d49fcfe377;o=1
Set-Cookie: GAESA=CkowMGM2MWIxMTdjN2ZlOWE2ZGE0ZDg4YjA4ZGE1OGEyYWIwMzkyMzU4MmRmMzkxMjU0Y2ExYTg3NmVhMTY1ZTBiYWM1Yzk1NjRlYxCf99_J8ys; expires=Sun, 19-Nov-2017 09:58:11 GMT; path=/
Date: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 09:58:11 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 35
Expires: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 09:58:11 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: I tried adding the following to the end of my script:
  ` self.response.set_cookie('GAESA', 'value', max_age=1, path='/',
                    domain='', secure=False)
  self.response.unset_cookie('GAESA') `
The cookie is gone now but it is also gone from the other scrips in the project so I do not know if it was the changes I made or if it disappeared when I uploaded the new version. I suspect the cookie has something to do with tracking.

Comment: You can always check if your change was responsible by reverting it temporarily - if the cookie re-appears then it is likely that your change made it go away :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe "GAESA" stands for "Google App Engine Session Affinity" and is a cookie set by the Google load balancers when you have [session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/using-websockets-and-session-affinity?tab=python#session_affinity) turned on. This question is one of the few results out there for "GAESA" and so I found it when wondering where this cookie came from in an app I have deployed on Google Cloud Run. After disabling session affinity the cookie is no longer set